# Android - Need to Pause playing mediafile at particular instance

Tags: java, android

I have a page consisting of three different Buttons PLAY | PAUSE | STOP.
PLAY | STOP is working fine, but i'm not able to pause at particular instance. I want to pause playing at an instance, by pressing pause button. And then resume it from saved instance by again pressing Play button.

Below is the code from Sound.java file

```
public class Sound extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer mp = null;
    String play = "Play!";      
    String stop = "Stop!";
    String pause = "Pause";     
    int length;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sound);

        final ImageButton play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.idplay);
        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                managerOfSound("play");
                Toast toast_play = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                        "Playing First", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast_play.show();

            } // END onClick()
        });

final ImageButton pause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.idpause);
        pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                managerOfSound("pause");
                Toast toast_pause = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
"Pausing Morning Bhajan-Aarati", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast_pause.show();

            } // END onClick()
        });


        final ImageButton stop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.idstop);
        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mp != null) {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.reset();
                    Toast toast_stop = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Stopping First",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast_stop.show();
                }
            } // END onClick()
        });


    /** Manager of Sounds **/
    protected void managerOfSound(String theText) {
if (mp != null){
        mp.reset();
        mp.release();
        }
        if (theText == "play")
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.goodbye);
        else if (theText == "pause" && mp.isPlaying())
mp.pause();
            length = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            mp.seekTo(length);
            mp.start();
    }
```

Here is my sound.xml file,

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/idplay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="65dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/image_play" />
        <!-- android:text="@string/idplay" /> -->

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/idpause"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/idstop"
            android:background="@drawable/image_pause" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/idstop"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/idplay"
            android:background="@drawable/image_stop" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Your Help is Appreciated..!!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is this line:

```
if (theText == "play")
  mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.goodbye);
else if (theText == "pause" && mp.isPlaying())
  mp.pause();
  length = mp.getCurrentPosition();
  mp.seekTo(length);
  mp.start();´
```

You are setting the length by clicking the pause button, but you will start it again directly in this if clause.

You should check if the play button is clicked if the media was playing befor, something like

```
if(length > 0)
```

and then start the player at the specified position.

Edit:
In addition, you should not use the operator `==` to compare strings. You should better use `string1.equals(string2)`

Hope it helps

Best wishes

Comment: Thanks for your response.. I have updated the string1.equals(string2) in the code. But for Pausing activity, can you please clarify exactly where should I make the changes and where to check if(length > 0)..

Comment: I dont know if you have done the check if a medai was played before in your MediaPlayer class. But if not you should develop an mechanism to play a media file on a specified positian as it was paused.